# Disable Chrome v 84 Issues Tab in JS console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to toggle on/off the "Issues" tab in the Chrome dev tools console?
It's a noble idea but I don't need it all the time. (Sorry I'm not allowed to post pictures inline but the links are below)

[The tab appears regardless of logging level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P7jq.png)

[The only way I know to hide it is to click "Go to Issues"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spAnY.png)

Clicking that button opens the lower console, and then I have to close the Issues tab every single time. I'm only working on a handful of pages and most of the issues are warnings that are out of my control (Same-Site cookies from 3rd parties etc.).

Comment: Obviously that JS can't change behavior of browser itself, so you can not do that via JS

Comment: Doesn't look like there is a way to turn it off in Chrome, so if it really bothers you maybe try to contact them to have them provide a way for the user to turn it off.  Of course it would take a lot of people complaining in order for them to do that, so it probably won't happen, but might as well try.

Comment: I had same issue with the Issue Tab. Sent a feedback via Chrome's help center and maybe you can try the same and hope it works..

Comment: What is it called in chrome flags please @wOxxOm

Comment: There's no more any flag to disable...

Comment: If you are developing a website, you can find a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63311280/7663959

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those answers were accepted. They might have been settings that were temporarily available.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good news. Chrome 85 will show it less frequently.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1068116#c25