# How to disable issue notifications in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Recently, an **Issues** panel has been added to Chrome, this one:

[image]

It's ok if the Chrome team wanted to add it to Chrome. The problem is that it shows notifications or alerts (I don't know how to call them) in the console. Something like this:

[image]

I find them quite annoying. Is there any way to disable them?

Comment: There's no way.

Comment: @wOxxOm Oh man! That sucks :(

Answer (score 1):

You can allow or block notifications from all sites or the one you want to block. Go to the Chrome setting on the top right and click on Privacy and security > Site settings > Notifications. Now here in notifications, you can block or allow all notifications.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It showed up everytime I reloaded the website I was developing.
The way I solved it was adding my website to Allow Insecure Content

- Go to Chrome Preferences
- Privacy Settings
- Insecure content
- Added my url to Allow group